# Creating a nested dictionary inside a dictionary using CSV file and comparing the values with other dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

```
for row in db:
            key = row.pop('name')
            print(key)
            if key in row:
                pass
            database[key] = row 
        print(database)
```

```
   (database[key] = {db.fieldnames[i]:row[i] for i in range(1,len(db.fieldnames))
if I try this instead of **database[key] = row**, I\'m getting 'KeyError 0'
```

I have a CSV file with 1st column name and few header columns. I wanted to create a dictionary with name as a key and values as another nested dictionary. The nested dictionary keys must be headers and values are the particular individual column data.

Till now I believe that I was able to achieve that using the above program. Can someone confirm whether its right or not? I also want to call out the values of the main dictionary(i.e the nested dictionary itself) and compare it with a dictionary I created in the other part of the program. If it matches it should give out the key(i.e name).

Example:

```
     dict = {'alice':{'age':32,'marks':86},'ron':{'age':25,'marks':75}}

     other = {'age':25,'marks':75}
```

By comparing the **other** and **dict.values**, I should get **ron** as a result.

```
sample csv file(original file has multiple rows and columns)

name  age  marks
alice  32   86
ron    25   75
```

Someone please guide me how to proceed.

Comment: Can you correct this code block `(database[key] = {db.fieldnames[i]:row[i] for i in range(1,len(db.fieldnames)) if I try this instead of **database[key] = row**, I\'m getting 'KeyError 0'`

Answer (score 0):

```
def database(file):
    d = {}
    f = csv.reader(file, delimiter =",")
    header = next(f)
    n = len(header)
    for row in f:
        d[row[0]] = {header[i]:row[i] for i in range(1,n)}
    return d
```

Thank you @Avishka Dambawinna.